# Magento2 CE Latest Release Object DOMDocument should be created

Tags: magento2

After I installed final Magento2 CE I got error as Object DOMDocument should be created . Anyone knows why? This is working fine in previous release version and there is sudden change when i transfer my module here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Magento 2.0.0 CE there are many changes are done.

You have to check for your module all .xml file. XML file header defination are changed.

You have to check all xml file xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation value from latest version core module and set that value in xml file.

```
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd".
```

You have to set new value for above location in your module all xml file.Your issue are solved after change xml value.

```
Also registation.php and composer.json file must need in module root.
```

Comment: Thanks for replying but it seems this solution neither works. Here is my xml for your reference. if you can have glance ,<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Namespace\Module\Block\View" name="somename"
                template="Namespace_Module::view.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>

Comment: plz share your xml file for more reference.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Namespace\Module\Block\View" name="somename"
                template="Namespace_Module::view.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>

Comment: you have to check all xml fle of your moduel, any xml file having mismatch node.This error comes because of tag mismatch in config file or remaining to close tag.