# Products on category page don´t show after upgrade to Magento 2.1 from 2.0.7

Tags: magento2, category

I'm having a problem on Magento 2.1.
Basically I've installed a new magento 2.1, and imported the database from the 2.0.7 I used to have. Everything works fine but the categories page, that doesn't show any product. If I go to a product by typeing the url, it shows me the product, I can add it to the cart, but when I go to /checkout/cart/, it gives me this error

> There has been an error processing your request
>
> Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.
>
> Error log record number: 1195280938107

So basically my issues are 2, not showing the products on any category page, and that error on the cart page.
Any suggestion to get this fixed?

Here is the content of the log:

```
a:4:{i:0;s:37:"Object DOMDocument should be created.";i:1;s:12232:"#0 /home/aspirede/public_html/magento210/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponent/Config/Reader.php(95): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Config\DomMerger->getDom()
#1 /home/aspirede/public_html/magento210/vendor/magento/module-ui/Model/Manager.php(258): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Config\Reader->read()
#2 /home/aspirede/public_html/magento210/vendor/magento/module-ui/Model/Manager.php(166): Magento\Ui\Model\Manager->prepare('26369629f85abbf...')
#3 /home/aspirede/public_html/magento210/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php(144): Magento\Ui\Model\Manager->prepareData('26369629f85abbf...')
#4 /home/aspirede/public_html/magento210/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php(124): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->create('26369629f85abbf...', NULL, Array)
#5 /home/aspirede/public_html/magento210/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php(93): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->generateComponent(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Data\Structure), '26369629f85abbf...', Array, Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor))
#6 /home/aspirede/public_html/magento210/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/GeneratorPool.php(86): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->process(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Context))
#7 /home/aspirede/public_html/magento210/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(327): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\GeneratorPool->process(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Context))
#8 /home/aspirede/public_html/magento210/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(89): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->generateElements()
#9 /home/aspirede/public_html/magento210/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(129): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->generateElements()
#10 /home/aspirede/public_html/magento210/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Builder.php(55): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks()
#11 /home/aspirede/public_html/magento210/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(65): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks()
#12 /home/aspirede/public_html/magento210/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config.php(197): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build()
#13 /home/aspirede/public_html/magento210/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config.php(217): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config->build()
#14 /home/aspirede/public_html/magento210/vendor/magento/module-checkout/Controller/Cart/Index.php(55): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config->getTitle()
#15 /home/aspirede/public_html/magento210/var/generation/Magento/Checkout/Controller/Cart/Index/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Index->execute()
#16 /home/aspirede/public_html/magento210/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(102): Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Index\Interceptor->execute()
#17 /home/aspirede/public_html/magento210/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#18 /home/aspirede/public_html/magento210/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Index\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#19 /home/aspirede/public_html/magento210/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Checkou...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Index\Interceptor), Array, 'contextPlugin')
#20 /home/aspirede/public_html/magento210/vendor/magento/module-store/App/Action/Plugin/Context.php(106): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#21 /home/aspirede/public_html/magento210/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Store\App\Action\Plugin\Context->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Index\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#22 /home/aspirede/public_html/magento210/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Checkou...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Index\Interceptor), Array, 'customer-app-ac...')
#23 /home/aspirede/public_html/magento210/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/App/Action/ContextPlugin.php(61): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#24 /home/aspirede/public_html/magento210/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Customer\Model\App\Action\ContextPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Index\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#25 /home/aspirede/public_html/magento210/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Checkou...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Index\Interceptor), Array, 'storeCheck')
#26 /home/aspirede/public_html/magento210/vendor/magento/module-store/App/Action/Plugin/StoreCheck.php(44): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#27 /home/aspirede/public_html/magento210/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Store\App\Action\Plugin\StoreCheck->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Index\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#28 /home/aspirede/public_html/magento210/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Checkou...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Index\Interceptor), Array, 'weee-app-action...')
#29 /home/aspirede/public_html/magento210/vendor/magento/module-weee/Model/App/Action/ContextPlugin.php(112): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#30 /home/aspirede/public_html/magento210/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Weee\Model\App\Action\ContextPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Index\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#31 /home/aspirede/public_html/magento210/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Checkou...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Index\Interceptor), Array, 'tax-app-action-...')
#32 /home/aspirede/public_html/magento210/vendor/magento/module-tax/Model/App/Action/ContextPlugin.php(91): Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#33 /home/aspirede/public_html/magento210/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Tax\Model\App\Action\ContextPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Index\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#34 /home/aspirede/public_html/magento210/var/generation/Magento/Checkout/Controller/Cart/Index/Interceptor.php(39): Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#35 /home/aspirede/public_html/magento210/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Index\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#36 /home/aspirede/public_html/magento210/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#37 /home/aspirede/public_html/magento210/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#38 /home/aspirede/public_html/magento210/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'requestPreproce...')
#39 /home/aspirede/public_html/magento210/vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php(94): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#40 /home/aspirede/public_html/magento210/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#41 /home/aspirede/public_html/magento210/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'install')
#42 /home/aspirede/public_html/magento210/vendor/magento/framework/Module/Plugin/DbStatusValidator.php(69): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#43 /home/aspirede/public_html/magento210/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#44 /home/aspirede/public_html/magento210/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'front-controlle...')
#45 /home/aspirede/public_html/magento210/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/VarnishPlugin.php(55): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#46 /home/aspirede/public_html/magento210/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\VarnishPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#47 /home/aspirede/public_html/magento210/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'front-controlle...')
#48 /home/aspirede/public_html/magento210/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php(73): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#49 /home/aspirede/public_html/magento210/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#50 /home/aspirede/public_html/magento210/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#51 /home/aspirede/public_html/magento210/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#52 /home/aspirede/public_html/magento210/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#53 /home/aspirede/public_html/magento210/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#54 {main}";s:3:"url";s:26:"/magento210/checkout/cart/";s:11:"script_name";s:21:"/magento210/index.php";}`
```

Comment: Could you please post the content of `var/report/1195280938107` in your question

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism I have added the content of the log

Comment: Possible related posts: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/90814/magento2-ce-latest-release-object-domdocument-should-be-created / http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/93783/error-object-domdocument-should-be-created-when-add-edit-product-attributes / http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92026/magento-2-module-object-domdocument-should-be-created-error

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism still haven't been able to solve the issue.. any suggestion?